# Using argparse.subparser with boolean values

Tags: python, argparse

I've read through the [Python argparse documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) several times and must be missing something huge.  I'm trying to add a makefile like syntax onto my cli tool, but despite the `--help` flag showing me the expected behavior the execution of it errors out:

> test.py

```py
import argparse
import os

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

    make_subparser = subparsers.add_parser("make")
    make_subparser.add_argument("update", action="store_false", help="Runs all make targets")
    make_subparser.add_argument("clean", action="store_false", help="Cleans up everything done previously")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.update:
        os.system("touch test.txt")

    elif args.clean:
        os.system("rm test.txt")

    else:
        print("Bad args, see: python test.py make --help.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Then in my terminal:

```sh
$> python test.py make --help
usage: test.py make [-h]

positional arguments:
  update      Runs all make targets

$> python test.py make update
usage: test.py [-h] {make} ...
test.py: error: unrecognized arguments: update
$> # this should make a file
$> 
$> python test.py make clean
usage: test.py [-h] {make} ...
test.py: error: unrecognized arguments: clean
$> # this should delete the file
```

This works fine if I swap out the `action="store_false"` for `action="store_true"`, but there's a dozen make commands so I only want to run the one that the user adds in the cli, if they try to enter any more it should exit.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `make` but I am with `argparse`. Could you expand the example with some more possible arguments to make it clear what you want to achieve? ATM I think you want an argument with `options`

Comment: The source of the error is escaping me, but note that having an argument *named* `update` doesn't mean you are restricted to *providing* the value `update` on the command line.

Comment: Sure, the functionality can be anything, but in general if I type `python test.py make X` I want to run some python code under `if args.x == True`.

Comment: `store_true` and `store_false` only make sense with `flagged` (`optionals`) arguments.  With `store_false`, ` --clean` flag would set `args.clean` to `False`, otherwise it would `True`.

Answer (score 1):

In the POSIX (and POSIX adjacent) world, boolean arguments are handled as *flags* which are passed via the command line as `--argument`. What you want isn’t boolean arguments (and that isn’t how Make treats them either), it’s simply a variable number of *positional arguments*, i.e. having [arity `*`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#nargs):

```
make_subparser.add_argument('targets', nargs='*')
```

This would be closest to how Make operates. However, from your command line it looks more like what you *actually* want is nested [subcommands](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands).

Comment: You're absolutely correct I was trying to do this with subcommands.  This cli already has some extra functionality using subparsers so I wanted to tack on a `make` simulator, and when I say boolean I meant "if the argument is present then I want to execute this code, else do nothing"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of separate boolean flags, use single argument `target` which allows a restricted set of values.

```
make_subparser.add_argument("target", choices=['update', 'clean'], help="Runs all make targets")

if args.target == "update":
    ...
elif args.target == "clean":
    ...
```

No `else` is needed, because any attempt to pass something other than `update` or `clean` will cause an error in `parse_args`, before `args.target` ever gets set.

Comment: This definately solves the problem, however now I lose the nice help descriptions, there's going to be about a dozen choices  each with a DAG behind it.